# getting all cafes in specific area without using center point and radius

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-places

I've this URL from which I can find all the Cafes in the defined area using google apis:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.272514,50.195682&radius=15000&types=cafe&key=<myAPI>
```

The area covered in the range above is within the circle shown below:

[image]

The actual area of the city I'm considering is as appearing below:

```
https://www.google.com.sa/maps/place/Al+Khobar/@26.2435009,50.0472298,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x3e49e839e8ef58d9:0xef778812d8b6aad1!8m2!3d26.2171906!4d50.1971381?hl=en
```

[image]

How can I get all the cafes which are exactly in this city (no more no less, without using radius)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging at Google Places API [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) I found this code, which looks to be fine for me:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=cafes+in+Khobar&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Comment: After trying to get all cafes in sydney by the query 'cafes+in+Sydney', only 60 records are returned. I reckon there should be much more cafes. Any idea please?

Comment: Because it's a text search, it performs a partial match of your query. Try https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Khobar&type=cafe&key=AIzaSyDAc91J9HvQ7bzyQqJzfQz38RcEjKamyEU

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the text search endpoint like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Khobar&type=cafe&region=SA&key=API_KEY

The tricky part comes when you want to specify concrete locations like:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Macdonalds+in+Toledo+in+Spain&type=restaurant&key=API_KEY

as it performs a partial match of your query and if you will enter some name composed of two strings(example Sweet Burger) that you know doesn't exist in that city, it'll still get you back to some places that encounter combinations of | sweet | burger | Toledo | Spain | but you'd expect to return [].